# How to stop access point wireless network from broadcasting SSID?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I want to create a hidden ap WiFi network in Ubuntu. I have thoroughly searched askubuntu, superuser and all other discussion forums.

I DO NOT need advise on whether or not hiding SSID improves security.

I just want only my phone to connect to WiFi and get some respite from every new guy dropping into my room asking my wifi password. I use hotspot in ubuntu by creating a wireless network and later changing its mode from infrastructure to ap.

I need to know how I can make it stop broadcasting it's SSID, like there is an option in regular wifi routers.

Comment: Look at using hostapd for this as it has a parameter that can disable broadcasting the SSID